# wierd behaivour of a global key

Tags: emacs

I've got in .emacs file:

```
(defun poc ()
  (interactive) 
  (insert (char-from-name "DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK"))
  (global-set-key [f12] 'poc))

(defun konc ()
  (interactive) 
  (insert (char-from-name "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK"))
  (global-set-key [(shift f12)] 'konc))
```

Entering F12 key I get

```
<f12> is undefined
```

If I enter M-x poc, DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK is inserted. But from this moment on if I enter F12 key again, the quotation mark is correctly inserted.
And this repeats after restarting emacs.
Is something wrong with this code?
emacs-version is 26.1

Comment: I've reformatted your code to give it the correct indentation.  Do you understand now why you're seeing that behaviour?

Comment: The answer below is quite comprehensive. I'm an emacs user, unfortunately don't know lisp.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the keys in the functions, so you need to run the functions first.  This is not recommended.  Bind the keys outside the functions, like so:

```
(defun poc ()
  (interactive) 
  (insert (char-from-name "DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK")))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") #'poc)
```

Since these are so simple (just inserting characters), you actually don't even need functions.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") (string (char-from-name "DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK")))
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f12>") (string (char-from-name "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK")))
```

or if you use an encoding like utf-8 (which you should), you can put the characters directly in a string.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") "„")
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f12>") "“")
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one, the simplest, is enough.